# Hibernate 5.2.12 to 5.6.15 migration

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to upgrade to 5.6.15 version of hibernate but facing issues with it. After changing maven pom version of hibernate, tomcat is not starting. I really don't know how to address this issue. May be this issue is just tipof iceberg.

I am using,
Java - 1.8.0_361
apache-tomcat-9.0.41
Current Hibernate - hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final

What will be right way to migrate? I mean step-by-step instructions.

I have enabled logs to see what is happening. But don't see any details. I think tomcat is stuck.

Comment: Hibernate `5.12` doesn't exist. Have you checked [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/)? You have all the docs for each version and a couple of them have a **Migration Guide**. If that is not enough, please provide more debugging details such as error logs in tomcat (maybe setting log level to DEBUG) could also help, what are the libraries that you are using, the version of your tomcat, the version of the jdk, etc, etc

Comment: Added more details in the questions. I dont see any details in log file. It is at Debug. And I am referring Migration Guide . But it is very high level and talks about features/bug fixes. Did you face any problems while migrating?

Comment: With that level of detail is hard to help you. You can find all the migrations guide for each version [here](https://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/). You are moving from `5.2.x` to `5.6.x`, which means that you have to check all the migrations guides between those two versions. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and no errors messages is almost impossible to suggest something, only guessings. Maybe try to upgrade from one `5.2` to `5.3` and so on to see if the problem is in 5.6 or before.

Comment: @GastónSchabas Thanks.. trying to migrate 5.3..will update on progress